# Adding a public static ipv4 address to an AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ipv4

I have a load balancer configured to have an IPV4 Ip address. However, the provided IP is a DNS mapped IP address to the load balancer of the format *.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

I need to configure IOT devices to send data to the load balancer and they do not support DNS. How can I assign a static IP address like *.*.*.* to my load balancer so that I can configure my IOT devices to send data to it.

The Elastic IPs section does not provide a facility to allocate it to a load balancer and only supports ec2 instances.

**Conclusion:**

I have found a way to use DNS on my IOT device and working on this was vital. I am now aware of the option of manually hosting a load-balancer on an EC2 instance. A simper alternative is forwarding all requests at an elastic IP addressed EC2 instance to the load balancer. However, this will cause a bottleneck at the transparent proxy. Hence, I think using the DNS feature on the IOT device is the best option.

Comment: ELB is a managed service that relies on DNS and you cannot configure a static IP. Consider using something like HAProxy running on EC2, with an Elastic IP.

Comment: Is that a proper solution, manual management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elastic Load Balancers do not support static IP addresses. They only support DNS CNAMEs (or Aliases if you are using Route 53). This is because ELB DNS entries will resolve to different IP addresses depending on how it is scaling between availability zones. Also, over time, the IP addresses will/may change.

The AWS documentation also specifically states to create CNAME-records only when mapping custom DNS entries to your ELB. If you are using Route 53, you can create an Alias record, which look like an A-record to the outside world.

If you need a static IP address, then you cannot use ELB.

Instead, you will need to manage your own load balancer (HAProxy, nginx, etc.) on an EC2 instance using an Elastic IP address.

Comment: What if I create an EC2 instance to forward requests to my load balancer?

Comment: You can do that. But like using HAProxy or nginx, you'll need to manage the load on your proxy since all requests will go through the single instance. Your single EC2 instance may become a bottleneck compared to available capacity of your ELB.

Comment: I understand, can you think of a better alternative?

Comment: If you need a single static IP address, then I don't think there are any alternatives. A single static IP address can only resolve to a single server. You could try something like AWS Kinesis which is designed to inject IoT traffic.

Comment: The fact your IoT devices don't support DNS is kind of scary: what happens if your IP address must change for some reason? Are your IoT devices now simple paper weights?

Comment: True, I did find out a way to use DNS on my IOT devices in the documentation. I will try to get it to work. Thank you for your detailed explanation and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible to assign a static IP with the elastic load balancer. You need to use DNS name only.

The only way I am aware of doing this is by setting up your instances within a VPC and having dedicated NAT instances by which all outbound traffic is routed.

Here is a link to the AWS documentation on how to set up NAT instances:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html

Comment: NAT instances (and NAT Gateways) are for **outbound** traffic, not inbound.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Elastic Load Balancer does not support assigning a static IP address due to many reasons.

Looking at your problem, the issue you are facing is having large amount of data sources to pump data to AWS. I suggest you to use [AWS Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/) service instead of the current approach as Firehose specifically focus on streaming data into AWS.